# Need to match a string with following regex format

Tags: java, regex

A String will be of format `[( 1.0N)-195( 1.0E)-195(28)-769.7(NESW)-1080.8(U)-617.9(43-047-30127)]`

I need a regex to match to see if the string contains `-XXX-XXX` (where `X` is a digit)

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=.*?(?:-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]))");

    if(p.matcher(a).matches())

    {
        System.out.println("Matched");
    }
```

Also I've tried `-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]` and `(?=.*?-[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9])`
Nothing worked

Comment: Don't you mean match 43-037-30149 but capture -037-30149 ?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear...I just want to check if the string contains -[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]

Comment: So you're not specifically looking for the string "-037-301" as stated in your question? [confused].

Comment: It's a confusing question indeed. I think that he wants to find '-XXX-XXX' where X is a number.

Comment: @NitheshReddy, please explain more of what you're wanting. What is the end result? A returned string of characters, or true/false?

Comment: Sorry Jonathan...I want it to be true or false

Comment: @NitheshReddy, OK true/false if what? If it contains "-037-301" or if it contains dash-num-num-num-dash-num-num, or what? You never defined the goal, so everyone's guessing.

Comment: If the string contains -[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9] it should return true else false..I hope it is clear now.. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A substring would be much easier, but `(?:\\d{2})(-\\d{3}-\\d{5})` will match -XXX-XXXXX as the 1 group.

I'm assuming the 3 digits in the last number was a mistake. If not just change the 5 to a 3.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the string contains -3digits-3digits

```
 String a = "43-037-30149";
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3})");
  if(p.matcher(a).matches())      
  {
     System.out.println("Matched");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use substring??

```
String b = a.substring(2,9);
```

or this one:

```
String c = a.substring(a.indexOf('-'), a.indexOf('-') + 8);
```

making "only" a substring would also be much more efficient! ;)